Gnome-Shell desktop-entry detach process
I have a vpn command : start-vpn provided by my company.
On Gnome-Shell I can open a terminal, type the command start-vpn type my password close the terminal and the VPN continue to run properly.
The command is interactive (it also imply to open a browser and connect first with MFA on web page).
In any case this is working, however if I try to create a desktop-entry so i can start it from gnome-shell menu :
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=VPN
Exec="/usr/bin/vpn-connect options"
Icon=/home/user/Pictures/logo.png
X-Shortcut-App=true
Terminal=true

Well this open a terminal but as soon as the connection is established the terminal is killed and the vpn process killed as well while if I open the terminal myself type the command and quit it works.
How can I have a desktop-entry that actually do not clean detached process ? nohup and disown are not an option as the vpn is interactive and spawn multiple other process. (please feel free to change my question if it's wrong).
